# How do I unit test my MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, dependency-injection

From what I understand unit testing is more about writing code that is actually testable than it is about writing the actual tests.

In order to write testable code, in languages like java at least, I should probably be using dependency injection right? the app I'm writing currently does not use any DI.

But I wanted to start by writing unit tests for my MainActivity which looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ImageButton buttonPlay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting the orientation to landscape
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        //Prevent screen from dimming when app is running
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        //getting the button and adding click listener
        buttonPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //starting game activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));
    }

}
```

Should I have a test for every method here? like one for onCreate(), setContentView(), setRequestedOrientation(), etc? Because Im not even sure what I would be asserting for those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either local unit testing (JVM based) or Espresso unit testing or both!
In simple terms, from local unit testing you can test whether calling a function (after mocking its dependencies if any) results in the calling of a certain desired function or not.
By Espresso unit testing you can test the flow of your application.
I would recommend [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html#0) codelab if you want to start unit testing in Android.

Comment: seems like googles docs recommend mockito (maybe thats different?), but Im just not sure if I should even be testing those methods at all?

Comment: No sir you dont need to test those method, although you may want to test what happens when you click on the button. You can test this scenario using Espresso unit testing

Comment: but if I shouldn't be directly testing native methods like setRequestedOrientation(), how do I confirm its set to the right orientation? Do i do that further down the line with one of my own methods?